# Flash message in symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, session, flash-message

I'm trying to set flash message from ContactAction then redirect on Homepage, but on it, I can't see my flash message, maybe my session is reset ? Can I have some help, I'm a beginer on Symfony.

CoreController that contain both index and contact functions :

```
<?php
namespace OC\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class CoreController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $ServiceAdverts = $this->container->get('oc_core.listAdverts');
        $adList = $ServiceAdverts->getListAdverts();

        return $this->render("OCCoreBundle:Core:index.html.twig", array(
        'listAdverts' => $adList
        ));
    }

    public function contactAction()
    {
        $this->addFlash('info', 'Contact page not ready yet !');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('oc_core_homepage');
    }
}
```

Twig template (homepage) :

```
{% block body %}

<div>
    Messages flash :
    {% for msg in app.session.flashBag.get('info') %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ msg }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
<h2>Liste des annonces</h2>

<ul>
    {% for advert in listAdverts %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('oc_platform_view', {'id': advert.id}) }}">
                {{ advert.title }}
            </a>
            par {{ advert.author }},
            le {{ advert.date|date('d/m/Y') }}
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li>Pas (encore !) d'annonces</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{{ path('oc_core_contact') }}">Contact</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I've just tested it, and for me, your code worked. Do you have any error?

Comment: @DanCostinel no :/ So what could be the problem ?

Comment: Cau you post the full code of your homepage twig template?

Comment: Done, you can see it now. Hope you'll find a solution :/

Comment: I can't see where you include the bootstrap code. Maybe you do that in a `base.html.twig` which then you don't extends anymore in your homepage twig template? I mean, in your homepage template, at the top, you should have something like this: `{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}`.

Comment: Ye I know, even with my layout and the bootstap css it still doesnt work.

Comment: Then clearly you have another problem, about which I can't tell you anything as I don't have the project source code.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 3.3 [made improvements to flash messages](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-improved-flash-messages) so your Twig template should look different.  The `app.session.flashBag.get()` call is now replaced by `app.flashes()`.

So your Twig code would now be:

```
{% for msg in app.flashes('success') %}
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ msg }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok let me try it.

Comment: So I tryed your code, when addflash is on the IndexAction (same page then) I works, but on contactAction, i cant see flash message when i get redirected on homepage

Comment: The page you are on shouldn't affect the flash message - it is likely that one of your templates doesn't have that Twig code to display it.

Comment: More could would be helpful, but Twig code is likelier to be the problem, that perhaps you aren't including/extending whatever has the flash Twig code

Comment: I edited my post you can see the full codde. And I don't think the problem comes from twig, As I said when I put the addflash inside indexAction function I can see it, but not when I put it inside contactAction. To be precise on my homepage I have a like that point on contactAction. But maybe I'm wrong

Comment: I still thing it's a Twig issue - I wouldn't put your Twig flash message code directly into a single template - it should be in all templates that are extended from your base.

Comment: I should put it on my layout you think ?

Comment: Yes - your base template.  Also use the Symfony profiler to see if an extra redirect might be happening, or if the message is actually in the session, etc.  That should help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works for me in 3.2 and 3.4

```
{% for type, flash_messages in app.session.flashBag.all %}
    {% for msg in flash_messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ type }}">
            {{ msg }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another thing is that once you called the flashBag it turns empty so you can't use it twice. Check your code that it hasn't been called on another page right before a second redirect ...

Comment: this the same, and I double checked I call it just one time on my home page :/